# Heroku: deploy Spray based service

Tags: scala, heroku, spray

I have a simple Scala project, that has several maven modules. It looks something like this:

```
Parent project
|- service1
|- service2
|-...
|- serviceN
 |- Procfile
 |- ...
 |- pom.xml
```

I was trying to deploy serviceN to heroku (right now, serviceN only, without the other services). In that service's directory, I have executed the following commands:

```
heroku create serviceN
git push heroku master
```

ServiceN is a Spray.io project, I'm trying to expose my web services on interface=0.0.0.0 and port=8080 (seen it on some example project).

When the push finishes, the we interface gives me :

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
```

when I run `heroku ps`, there is no output. When I run `heroku scale web=1` I get the error:

```
Scaling dynos... failed
 !    Couldn't find that formation.
```

My Procfile (no extension, capital P at the beginning) looks like this (I build with maven, so my app is recognized as a Java app):

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/serviceN.jar com.service.ObjectWithMain
```

When I look into the logs, I see this:

```
2015-11-22T20:11:11.886773+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="MY_WS_ENDPOINT" host=serviceN.herokuapp.com request_id=71fad213-66d5-4186-a9fd-20ef505908e9 fwd="91.104.133.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-22T20:11:12.217106+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=static-data-service.herokuapp.com request_id=cabd051a-1e37-4edd-841b-4a0eb875baf6 fwd="91.104.133.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Please hep me find out what I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Procfile must exist in the root directory of the Git repo. The commands in the Procfile must also be relative to the root dir (which will be the current working dir when heroku runs it).

Comment: Also the pom.xml must be in the root (or a parent pom.xml). If you require subdirs, i recommend using Git submodules

Comment: Right, after a quick `git remote -v` it's obvious that my current project structure is not a good fit for what I try to accomplish. Submodules look promising, thanks for your answer.